# Android Studio 's animation xml file code completion not work

Tags: android-studio

'android:duration' and some other attribute don't show when typing.
 Any help would be appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change API level and try it.. It may work for you

Comment: thanks for your help, I change API level to 25 and 23,but it does not work